# How to convert surrogate pair characters?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a web service that takes an XML String as input and it is primarily in UTF-8. However, there is a possibility that surrogate pairs can get mixed into the string and those particular characters become unreadable when it is being processed by my application.

I am reading in an xml file like so (I have a feeling this part messes things up):

```
String xmlFile = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.xml")),"UTF-8");
```

I know that I can detect this with when I loop through every character in the string:

```
Character.isSurrogatePair(high, low)
```

What I want to know is if there is a way to convert a surrogate pair to something that can be recognized properly in UTF-8. For example "" is recognizable in UTF-8 since it has 3 bytes but "" has 4 bytes (surrogate pair) but the graphical display is identical.

Comment: Did you try with only **Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.xml"))**

Comment: Yes and I’ve also tried pasting the entire xml string into my java class and running in a test. The characters are displayed just fine in eclipse, but it becomes different characters at runtime when assigned to a String variable.

Comment: String, char and Character use UTF-16. Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 can encode the entire Unicode character set. No problem.

Comment: Then their might be something fishy with the file im processing like the person commented below, I’ll have a look and update later.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code is 100% fine** (if the encoding is indeed UTF-8). *Surrogate pairs* is a way UTF-16 encode a Unicode code point as two `char`s (2x2 bytes). That is covered by UTF-8 as a longer multibyte sequence (upto 6 bytes, in 2017).

Unicode itself just numbers code points (symbols). Those numbers are then encoded with UTF-*nn* so no errors can happen such as searching the byte for `/` and finding it falsely. UTF-8 uses high bits, and UTf-16 does a similar trick, with "surrogate pairs." Unicode & UTF is a solid design.

Now Unicode did grow over time, and the standards expanded likewise.

So running with java 6 you might not have the same Unicode power (range) as later versions. Likewise old non-java programs and fonts might have their white spots.

Most likely something in the data is fishy. Reading byte blocks and converting every block to a String would cause invalid characters at block boundaries.